# PHP ob_flush question

Tags: php

Is ob_flush necessary and what does it do exactly? I ask because I have at the bottom of my footer and for some reason its not letting me destroy a session variable correctly.

code.

```
if(isset($_GET['a']) && is_numeric($_GET['a'])) {
    if(isset($_SESSION['page']) && $_SESSION['page'] !== $_GET['a']){
        unset($_SESSION['page']);
    }

    $page = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, htmlentities(strip_tags($_GET['a'])));
    $_SESSION['page'] = $page;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you've used `ob_start`, then `ob_flush` will output everything that would normally have been printed out since `ob_start` was called.  Post some code for more detailed help.

Comment: what kind of code would you like I have plenty where the problem is happening at this is why I asked instead of posting tons code.

Answer (score 0):

ob_start() will turn output buffering on. While output buffering is active no output is sent from the script (other than headers), instead the output is stored in an internal buffer. 
ob_flush() will output all the content stored in the internal buffer.

Ob_Start() must be used at the beginning of the code and ob_flush() at the end.

It may be used because the user may be trying to redirect to another page and show some message on it.

It may not allow the you to destroy the session because it may be stored in the internal buffer.

Comment: can i leave out ob_flush and keep ob_start?

Comment: @tang - No.  Nothing would get sent to the browser.  Post the code where you're trying to destroy your session variable for starters.

Comment: @tang remove both ob_start and ob_flush, then try to destroy the session.let me know the result.